# What does "Watermelon makes me clean" mean?

Tags: word-meaning

I am watching a [youtube video, "Largest Watermelon? World's Largest Fruit"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=2LeMuL8Xz74) and there's a comment with many likes saying:

> Watermelon makes me clean

What does the word *clean* mean here?

Comment: It might help if you edited to tell us what was going on before the statement and who was in the scene.

Comment: @mdewey It's from the comments section about the video, not from the video itself. The video is clickbaity so I'm not going to watch it much of it, but I glances at the section about watermelons and they were talking about the history and various trivia type facts about watermelon.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clean), the word *clean* can be defined as

> free from dirt or pollution
>
> free from contamination or disease
>
> UNADULTERATED, PURE

Therefore, the speaker likely had in mind that the consumption, or use of watermelon results in one of the aforementioned states.

Comment: I feel like there is an in-joke that you are not explaining.

Comment: @Polygnome You think that there's some kind of innuendo attached to the use of 'clean' here?

Comment: Not necessarily. It probably is just be as simple as watermelon makes people feel purified, because it removes oxidants, or whatever gunk is in their system. Watermelon does have a lot of vitamin C in it.

Comment: @TheRealMeal I am not sure. But I fail to see what property of watermelon it is that makes one clean. They are a somewhat healthy food, but that is about it. What is it about watermelons that makes one clean? This makes me think that there is a hidden meaning behind the phrase that I'm simply not getting. A meme perhaps I've not yet seen.

Comment: @Polygnome - Abundance of vitamin C. Remember that you're asking us to comment on a context-less comment. :o Without context, nobody can know for sure, so you have to assume that it is what it appears to be, nothing more.

Comment: @FeliniusRex Phrases often enough mean more than just what is found in a dictionary. Its not unreasonable to assume that there is a hidden meaning behind it that someone would know and be able to comment on. Im not asking to speculate, I'm asking if someone *knows*. Example: "All your base are belong to us" isn't just *bad grammar*, there is a lot cultural background that a non-native speaker might not know.

Comment: @Polygnome There is no cultural context here.